# What is causing this Python exception?

Tags: python, exception, attributes

I have a C++ app that uses Python to load some scripts. It calls some functions in the scripts, and everything works fine until the app exits and calls Py_Finalize. Then it displays the following: (GetName is a function in one of the scripts)

Exception AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute 'GetName'" in 'garbage collection' ignored
Fatal Python error: unexpected exception during garbage collection

Then the app crashes.
I'm using Python 3.1 on Windows. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs to Py_Finalize():

> Bugs and caveats: The destruction of
>   modules and objects in modules is done
>   in random order; this may cause
>   destructors (`__del__()` methods) to
>   fail when they depend on other objects
>   (even functions) or modules.
>   Dynamically loaded extension modules
>   loaded by Python are not unloaded.
>   Small amounts of memory allocated by
>   the Python interpreter may not be
>   freed (if you find a leak, please
>   report it). Memory tied up in circular
>   references between objects is not
>   freed. Some memory allocated by
>   extension modules may not be freed.
>   Some extensions may not work properly
>   if their initialization routine is
>   called more than once; this can happen
>   if an application calls
>   Py_Initialize() and Py_Finalize() more
>   than once.

Most likely a `__del__` contains a call to `<somemodule>.GetName()`, but that module has already been destroyed by the time `__del__` is called.